# Wait for objects and IOCP at the same time

Tags: c++, windows

I have a event loop which can wait for HANDLEs(like `Event`) and fire corresponding events. Is it possible to wait for IOCP handles at the same time?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. One of the few things *not* in the list of waitable objects with the regular/enhanced wait functions are IOCP handles. And GetQueueCompletionStatus (and the ex version) wait *only* on IOCP handles (obviously), but they *are* alertable, if that helps at all (I doubt it).

Comment: Typically when you start an asynchronous IO operation you have to provide an event handle.  Depending on the program structure, it may be possible for any number of IOCP-based asynchronous IO operations to (carefully!) share a single event which you can wait on.  The main thing to watch out for is that the event is cleared whenever a new IO operation is started, so you have to check that the IOCP queue is empty before waiting on the event, and make sure that only the one thread is issuing IO against this particular queue.